# Android  Listview with Labelled Sections

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have to create a list of informations under different labels (titles). I have found a sample for "Alphabetically ordered ListView with labelled sections" (http://androidseverywhere.info/JAAB/?p=6). But my requirment is when scrolling this list it will replace the current heading label with another one. I have found this working on iPhone. Anybody around here to help?

Comment: Link is not working... "forbidden"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this project](http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/) looks like what you're after.

Comment: Thanks.This is what am looking for. :)